# Organizing GLSL shaders in OpenGL engine

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader

Which is better ?

1. To **have one shader program with a lot of uniforms** specifying 
   lights to use, or mappings to do (e.g. I need one mesh to be parallax mapped, and another one parallax/specular mapped). I'd make a cached list of uniforms for lazy transfers, and just change a couple of uniforms for every next mesh if it needs to do so.
2. To  **have a lot of shader programs** for every needed case, each one with small amount of uniforms, and do the lazy bind with **glUseProgram** for every mesh if it needs to do so. Here I assume that meshes are properly batched, to avoid redundant switches.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Most modern engines I know have a "shader cache" and use the second option, because apparently it's faster.

Also you can take a look at the ARB_shader_subroutine which allows dynamic linkage. But I think it's only available on DX11 class hardware.

Comment: I believe that's correct. Seeing as OpenGL4 somewhat represents DX11 in features, I went ahead and looked at the "changelog" for 4.1, and there it seems to be (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opengl#OpenGL_4.1): "Reduced shaders compilation times with the ability to query and load a binary for shader program objects"

Comment: One thing to note here is that even engines that maintain a cache of many shaders at runtime may be generating the bulk of those shaders from a common uber-sbader source file, with compiler directives used to turn parts of it on or off as needed for each combination of features in play. So the development/edit-time experience may be more similar to point 1, through the runtime effect is more like point 2.

Answer (score 15):

Generally, option 2 will be faster/better unless you have a truly huge number of programs.  You can also use buffer objects shared across programs so that you need not reset any values when you change programs.

In addition, once you link a program, you can free all of the shaders that you linked into the program.  This will free up all the source code and any pre-link info the driver is keeping around, leaving just the fully-linked program in memory.

Comment: What are those buffer objects ?

Comment: Probably Vertex Buffer Objects's.

Comment: Uniform Buffer Objects, a new feature in GL4.

Comment: @ChrisDodd according to this (http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Uniform_Buffer_Object), UBO's were introduced with OpenGL 3.1. Which makes it far more likely that a user will be able to use them (even linux has a lot of GL3.1 capable hardware+drivers these days).

Answer (score 0):

I would tend to believe that it depends on the specific application. And yes since it would be more efficient to say run 100 programs where they each may have about 2-16 uniforms each; it may be better to have a trade off of the two. I would tend to think that having say maybe 10 - 20 programs for your most common shading techniques would be sufficient or a few more. For example you might want to have one program / shader to do all your bump mapping, one to do all of your fog effects, one to do reflections, one to do refractions.

Now outside the scope of your question I think it would pertain here as well, one thing to incorporate into your engine would be a BatchProcess & BatchManager class setup to reduce the amount of CPU - GPU calls over the bus as this would prove efficient as well. I don't think there is a 1 fits all solution to your question as I would believe that it would be application specific just as setting up the relationship between how many batches (buckets) of vertices (primitives) your engine would have and how many vertices each of those batches would contain.

To try to make this a bit more clear: one game might have 4 containers or batches where each batch can hold up to 10,000 vertices to be considered to be full before the BatchManager decides to empty that bucket sending all of those vertices to the Graphics Card for the Rendering pipeline to be processed and drawn where a different game may have 10 buckets with 5,000 vertices, or another game might have 8 buckets with 12,0000 vertices.

So there could be a trade off of trying to combine the two according to your needs. If you have 1 single program with 100s of uniforms; the single program is easier to manage within the pipeline, but the shaders would be over cumbersome to read and manage. Then again have shaders with very few uniforms is quite easy to read and manage but having 100s of programs is a little harder to manage on the CPU before linking and sending them to be rendered properly. I would personally try to find a middle ground to where I have enough programs to do each specific task that is completely unique from each other such as doing fog density on one and a volumetric shadow mapping on another where each program has just enough uniforms to do the calculations required.

The next step would then be to do some bench mark testing to see where you efficiency and your overhead are balanced to make the appropriate adjustments.