# combine two shaders properties into one shader in opengl es 20?

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I have these two shaders i want these two to combine one shader draws texture perfectly and the other draw colors of lines perfectly?

```
private final String fragmentShaderCode =
        "precision lowp float;              \n"
                +"uniform vec4 uTex0;       \n"
                +"void main(){              \n"
                +" gl_FragColor = uTex0;    \n"
                +"}                         \n";
```

other one

```
private final String fCode =
        "precision mediump float;                                    \n"
                +"uniform sampler2D uTex0;                           \n"
                +"uniform vec4 uTex1;                                \n"
                +"varying vec2 v_TexCoordinate;                      \n"
                +"void main(){                                       \n"
                +" gl_FragColor = texture2D(uTex0, v_TexCoordinate); \n"
                +"}                                                  \n";
```

when i use the first one it will draw line colors perfectly but when i use the second one the line colors will be of the texture color how can i control this?
if i use the just second shader result is like this
[image]

lines are black but in actual i am setting line colors like this through handle

```
texHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(sProgram, "uTex0");
GLES20.glUniform4fv(texHandle, 1, LineColor, 0);
```

it should draw like this

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing up two concepts.

**Set line color as uniform vec4**:
Your first shader reads the line color as a 4-element vector. This is perfectly valid, but you should use a better variable name. For example `uniform vec4 lineColor;`. In your Java code, you then set the uniform value with

```
lineColorHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(sProgram, "lineColor");
GLES20.glUniform4fv(lineColorHandle, 1, LineColor, 0);
```

**Set texture unit as uniform sampler2D**:
Your second shader has `uTex0` declared as `uniform sampler2D uTex0;`. In this case, uTex0 is not a 4-element vector. It is an integer index that tells your shader to which texture unit uTex0 is bound to. You should set the uniform like this:

```
texHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(sProgram, "uTex0");
GLES20.glUniform1i(texHandle, 0); // 0 is default texture unit.
```

Comment: But how can i combine these two shaders so that when i need linecolor it takes vec4 but when i need sampler2d it takes utext0..i don't want to use two shaders as attaching and detaching shaders is heavy.

Comment: i want something like this     private final String fCode =
            "precision mediump float;                  \n"
                    +"uniform sampler2D uTex0;                  \n"
                    +"uniform vec4 linecolor;                  \n"
                    +"varying vec2 v_TexCoordinate; \n"
                    +"void main(){                              \n"
                    +" gl_FragColor = texture2D(uTex0, v_TexCoordinate); \n"
 +" gl_FragColor = linecolor; \n"
                    +"}                                         \n";

Comment: The question if it's better to use a single fat shader or several small ones was for example discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649801/organizing-glsl-shaders-in-opengl-engine?rq=1 . glUseProgram() isn't _that_ expensive.